# How to export blog posts from sharepoint 2010 and import them in new blog in sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, export, blog, import

Which is the best way of exporting blog posts from sharepoint 2010 to blog in sharepoint 2016. (from a blog subsite to a blog subsite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the things in this way:

1. Exporting the posts using Central Administration
   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428301.aspx
2. After that I used SharePoint Management shell in order to import the
   posts in the new blog site.
   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428322.aspx

Comment: Please mark it as the answer if it answered to your original question/problem. Additionally, if you can add some steps in more detail and how they were executed, that would be really great and likely help others in the future!